# Having trouble with WooCommerce Storefront child theme single.php "related posts" modification

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic, child-theme

I'd like to display posts from one category that have been posted in the past week. I've done this using `query_posts()` but have read about what a bad idea that is.

So, I've tried to make a function I can modify and place into my `functions.php` and then invoke directly or through an action in the `single.php` single blog post template for my child theme.

My function has never worked and was hoping for some help figuring out what I'm doing wrong.

```
function new_function() {
//Arguments
$args = array(
                            'post_type' => array( 'post' ),
                            'category_name' => 'classifieds',
                            'post_status' => array( 'publish' ),
                            'date_query' => array( 'after' => '1 week ago' ),
);
//Query
$new_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $new_query->have_posts() ) {
        $string .= '<ul>';
        while ( $new_query->have_posts() ) {
            $new_query->the_post();
            $string .= '<li>';
            $string .= '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
        } else {
        }
}
$string .= '</ul>'
return $string;
wp_reset_postdata();

}
```

Once the above has gone into my `functions.php`, my Wordpress site turns into blank pages.

One (sad) and sneaky additional question: once this function is not making my pages go blank, what is the best way to invoke it? Do I want this in the main `if have_the_posts()` query in `single.php` (for example) or should I invoke it outside of that query?

I know there are plugins that allow this type of functionality, but I'm going to do a bunch of formatting and further customization.

**EDIT**

Thanks to the help provided in the answer below, my code now works and looks like this:

```
function classified_stream() {
    //Arguments: posts, in classifieds category, that are published, and from the past week
    $new_args = array(
                    'post_type' => array( 'post' ),
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'category_name' => 'classified',
                    'date_query' => array( 'after' => '1 week ago' ),
    );
    //Query
    $new_query = new WP_Query( $new_args ); 
    //Trouble shooting with print_r - I realized I called the wrong category in an earlier version of function.
    //print_r($new_query);

    if ( $new_query->have_posts() ) :
            while ( $new_query->have_posts() ) : $new_query->the_post();
                echo '<p><a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_title() .'</a></p>';
    endwhile;
    endif;      
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
add_action( 'storefront_page_after', 'classified_stream',     20 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting a white screen is you never defined "$string".  You only concatenated it.

In the future you can find your errors when creating functions by turning wp_debug to true in your wp_config.php file.

Here is code that should work:

```
function new_function() {
  //Arguments: posts, in classifieds category, that are published, and from the past week
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'post' ),
    'category_name' => 'classifieds',
    'post_status' => array( 'publish' ),
    'date_query' => array( 'after' => '1 week ago' ),
  );
  //Query
  $new_query = new WP_Query( $args );

  if ( $new_query->have_posts() ) {
        $string = '<ul>';
        while ( $new_query->have_posts() ) {
            $new_query->the_post();
            $string .= '<li>';
            $string .= '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
        } else {
        }
  }
  wp_reset_postdata();
  $string .= '</ul>'
  return $string;
}
```

I would try to give your function a more practical name as well, but when you're ready to call the function you can do that by (in a php file):

```
echo new_function();
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
function new_function() {
  //Arguments: posts, in classifieds category, that are published, and from the past week
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'post' ),
    'category_name' => 'classifieds',
    'post_status' => array( 'publish' ),
    'date_query' => array( 'after' => '1 week ago' ),
  );
  //Query
  $new_query = new WP_Query( $args );
  $string = '';
  if ( $new_query->have_posts() ) {
        $string = '<ul>';
        while ( $new_query->have_posts() ) :
            $new_query->the_post();
            $string .= '<li>';
            $string .= '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
  }
  $string .= '</ul>'
  return $string;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! I set wp-config.php's debug to TRUE and was informed that the `else` bit of my code was causing a problem. That `$string` bit is still causing me a problem. I think using it outside and inside the `if` statement isn't working.

At least I'm not getting a white screen now.

Comment: After dealing with lots of little problems, I was able to get the code to work. I've edited my original post above with a version that runs on my site.

Comment: try the updated code i put up.  Yours will cause a problem if there are no posts as string isn't defined.  I cleaned it up a bit too

Comment: Yes, I was using the wrong category name and thus my query delivered no posts and `$string` was causing trouble. I've created a slightly different version of my function to do away with this issue - but now I will incorporate your changes. Whew. Thank you!